# Unable to disable Google Analytics via Spring to address DS-2718 (failed GA connections prevent file downloads) when building DSpace 5.3 with Mirage 2

Tags: spring, maven, ant, dspace

I'm working on a fresh installation of stock DSpace 5.3 (Windows Server 2012, Tomcat 8.0, Maven 3.2.5, Ant 1.9.6). This particular instance will be a dark archive without Google Analytics enabled; we don't currently have a GA account or analytics key, although we plan to register one eventually for a separate public-facing instance.

As per the problem described in [JIRA ticket DS-2718](https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-2718), DSpace hangs with the following message in dspace.log when I attempt to download a bitstream:

> 2015-10-20 09:52:02,324 INFO  org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec
>   @ I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing
>   request to {s}->https://www.google-analytics.com:443: Network is
>   unreachable: connect
>
> 2015-10-20 09:52:02,324 INFO  org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec
>   @ Retrying request to {s}->https://www.google-analytics.com:443

Since we won't be using GA on this instance, disabling it in Spring is a good workaround until the issue is resolved. As per the instructions, I commented out the Google Analytics entry in `dspace-5.3-src-release\dspace-xmlui\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml`, disabled Tomcat and rebuilt DSpace. An initial attempt running `mvn package -Dmirage2.on=true` still produced the problem, so I tried a "ground up" rebuild:

```
cd d:\dspace-5.3-src-release\dspace
mvn clean package -U -Dmirage2.on=true
[successful build]
cd d:\dspace-5.3-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer
ant update
[successful update]
[copy webapps to Tomcat 8.0\webapps and start Tomcat]
```

Even after the rebuild, however, I'm still getting the same error, with the same java.net.SocketException in dspace.log.

Not sure why this isn't working. Have I missed a step or setting in the rebuild process so that the change to `applicationContext.xml` isn't being applied?

FWIW, I tried grepping for "google" in dspace-5.3-src-release\dspace-xmlui-mirage2 to see if this could be a Mirage 2 problem, but I don't see anything that looks relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved itself after I ran `mvn clean -Dmirage2.on=true` in both `[dspace-src]` and `[dspace-src]\dspace`. I'm guessing that the issue originated on our end due to someone running a maven build from the wrong directory.

I've also removed the default key from `dspace-defaults.cfg` as suggested. Everything's now working.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to why you're still seeing the SocketException, but the real fix for the problem you're describing is to remove the default GA key from `dspace-services/src/main/resources/config/dspace-defaults.cfg`, see https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/commit/5b84fef1ad789443d06c338558a92f854b20c8ef. Have you tried doing that?